# How can I write __float128 data type to binary file?

Tags: c, fwrite, quadruple-precision

I am using quadmath library for quad-precision.
Can I use fwrite function to write to binary file?

```
struct rec
{ 
   __float128 mydata;
}

struct rec my_record;

mydata=1.41421356237309504880q;
fwrite(&my_record, sizeof(struct rec), 1, myfile);
```

Comment: Please add a language tag.

Comment: [tag:c]? [tag:c++]? Something else?

Comment: Sure you can.  Are you experiencing some problem or is this just a theoretical question?

Answer (score 0):

You should have no problem writing to a file.  As long as you read it back in the same way (i.e. with `fread`) and the file isn't copied between machines you should be fine.

You also don't need to encapsulate the value in a struct to do this:

```
__float128 mydata;
int rval;

mydata=1.41421356237309504880q;

rval = fwrite(&mydata, sizeof(mydata), 1, myfile);
if (rval < 1) {
    perror("failed to write record");
} 

...

rval = fread(&mydata, sizeof(mydata), 1, myfile);
if (rval < 1) {
    perror("failed to read record");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: @MikelAntoñana Glad I could be of assistance.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.